# Install an android application through another application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I need to create an application that will install some apk (the name is myapp.apk) file that I created. (I checked myapp.apk alone and it works fine)

I've created a folder `raw` inside the `res` folder and put the myapp.apk file there.
I added the following code to my application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("R.raw.myapp")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

But I'm getting a parse error on the emulator (eclipse android emulator).

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

First, `R.raw.myapp` is not a file. It is an integer identifier of a raw resource.

Second, you cannot install an APK from a resource (or an asset, or a `ContentProvider`). It must be a file on the filesystem, readable by other processes.

So, use `getResources().openRawResource()` to get an `InputStream` on your APK, write it to external storage, then use the file on external storage in your `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Is it possible to read it from the internal storage?
Basically what I want to do (and very confused on how to approach this the right way), is that other apps will be able (when given sdk and apk of my app) to add it to their app and by doing so, my app could also be installed. (my app is a simple one that just creates a webview of my website).

Thanks again

Comment: @dev: "Is it possible to read it from the internal storage?" -- only if you jump through hoops to make it world-readable. To be blunt, your description sounds an awful lot like malware (App B being installed as part of running App A). If your app "just creates a webview of [your] website", just have your "sdk" launch the URL of your Web site into the user's chosen browser, and dump the install-the-APK approach altogether.